# When do you enter the Mighty Mech?

Tags: untagged

In Tiny Epic Mechs when you enter the zone with the power mech, it says you "immediately take control of it". I was wondering where this falls in relation to other things that happen immediately. Specifically, mines, power up and attacking other players.

- A mine could prevent you from getting the Mighty Mech as you'd lose health.
- It would greatly affect a battle, whether you're in the suit or not.
- Being able to heal or power up and jump into the Mighty Mech in one step would be very useful.

The order of actions I know are:

Mines -> Combat -> Turrets -> Action

Where should entering the mighty mech fall into this?

[image: mighty mech rules]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general consensus in BGG is that entering the Mighty Mech is the first thing to do when entering a square, before any other action or check. So if otherwise allowed you could first enter inside the MM and then check for mines, combat, actions, etc.

But I could not find a written rule or clarification on the web.